# Is it possible to transfer a microSD with Ubuntu OS image to different Pi models?

Tags: sd-card, image, raspberry-pi-imager

My Raspberry Pi 3B seems to be slow and hangs when I try to install packages, however, I still want to use it due to its low power usage compared to newer Pi's.

I just wanted to know if I can use a more powerful Pi, like the Raspberry Pi 5 or even other brands, to install packages using their better hardware specs onto a microSD card, and then move the microSD to the Raspberry Pi 3B.  Would there be compatibility issues, say due to the fact that package installations and software updates were performed using a different model?

The operating system I am working with is Lubuntu.

Comment: I feel that your question *wanders off* into the **off-topic** category when you include other brands (i.e. **Orange Pi 5**)... this SE is ***Raspberry Pi***, not Orange Pi. I'd *suggest* you edit your Q to remove the Orange-branded models.

Comment: Well that's a bummer, since it seems the only SE where mentioning both brands are appropriate would be StackOverflow and I don't know if my question will have a decent likelihood of getting responses if I ask there.  But it's not like I need a different brand of SBC to solve my problem.

Comment: I personally don't know enough about OrangePi to make the call. It was just a suggestion. FWIW, I see no (0) "Close" votes, so I think you'll be fine. As to your question: It has been said forever that SD cards are interchangeable between models; e.g. take an SD from an RPi4 & swap it to an RPiB+ - no problem. What I don't know is whether that holds true with the new RPi5, and some of the changes *they* have made to the installation procedure - i.e. [rPi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#raspberry-pi-imager)

Answer (score 1):

The latest 32 bit Raspberry Pi OS is usable in all models and earlier OS work in models available at the time of introduction (provided that they are up to date).

The 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS works in all 64 bit models (Pi3 or later).

The Pi5 (if you can get one) only supports Bookworm 64 bit which currently only "works" on Pi4 or 5 and is still incomplete.

The same can not be said for Ubuntu (version unspecified) as there are multiple versions available for different processors but may; you can try. Some have ARM7 or ARM8 specific apps.